# Why is LyX not allowing numbered chapters in my book?

Tags: lyx, chapters, book-design

LyX v2.0.6 on Linux. Document class is [`book`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/book) (extra font sizes).

**Scenario**

I have a master document including two child documents (so far), both of which are the same document class as the master. The first child has some non-numbered chapters (chapter*). The second child document begins with Part I, after which I want to begin numbered chapters.

I begin a new paragraph (hit Return) and select Chapter from the style drop-down. I get a big bold "Chapter 1". So far, so good.

**Problem**

Almost anything I do after that makes the Chapter heading disappear.

For example, I pasted in text for the first paragraph of the chapter but it appeared in Chapter style. Changing it to Standard made the chapter heading disappear. Then I inserted another line above the paragraph and changed that to a chapter. Then, when I press the down arrow to continue editing my text, the heading disappears again.

**My question**

How can I have a book that consists of Parts with numbered chapters in LyX?

**Update**

The chapters stay if they have a non-empty name. I don't really want to name them, but it seems I can use a hard space (ctrl+space). Am I thereby Doing It Wrong, or is this an appropriate workaround for the situation?

Comment: There's no problem using entirely empty chapter names in `book` so I assume this is a LyX issue. I think LyX allows you to enter code directly but I've never used it so don't know the details. But `\chapter{}` will do what you want.

Comment: Either the LyX developers hasn't taken this into consideration, or it is a bug. Either way, if it isn't fixed in LyX 2.1 I'd file a bug report at http://www.lyx.org/trac/wiki/BugTrackerHome Your workaround is better than writing `\chapter{}` in an ERT (Ctrl + L), as the chapters show up in the Outline view.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. and @scav thanks for pointing this out. I believe that the general recommendation is the ctrl+space work around. Is that a bad idea from a LaTeX perspective? Is there any case where `\chapter{~}` would be rendered differently than `\chapter`? This is not just a book + chapter issue, right? I believe it is the same with any numbered section.

Comment: @scottkosty I guess it's the same with any numbered section, but I haven't tested. They do render differently though, just try `\documentclass[openany]{book}
\begin{document}
\chapter{}
Lorem ipsum
\chapter{~}
Lorem ipsum
\end{document}`. Notice there is more whitespace before Lorem ipsum in the second case. Screenshot: http://imgur.com/UeIqBpX. (scav: This would be a reason for preferring ERTs. It didn't occur to me when I wrote my previous comment.)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. thanks for the clear example. I see what you mean.

Comment: how about instead of ctrl+space, do an empty ERT box (or an empty LyX note). Not ideal, but solves the spacing issue that @Torbjørn T. pointed out. Note that my previous statement that "I believe that the general recommendation is the ctrl+space" is wrong. If anything, I believe it's an empty ERT box.

Comment: @scottkosty An empty ERT box is indeed better. Of course, whether spacing is an issue does depend on how chapter titles are set. In `scrbook` for example, the number is on the same line as the chapter title, similar to `\section`s in the standard classes, and then it's not a problem.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. thanks. If anyone wants to post that as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. should write the answer. Thanks for the explanations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best workaround seems to be adding an empty ERT box (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>) or LyX Note in the chapter title. This will create the LaTeX code `\chapter{}` for the chapter heading:

[image]

The reason adding a hard space/non breaking space (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>) is not ideal, is that for the standard classes where the chapter title is set on a separate line (below *Chapter N*), this will generate additional vertical space compared to the above, demonstrated by this minimal LaTeX example. `~` is a non breaking space.

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\begin{document}
\chapter{}
Lorem ipsum
\chapter{~}
Lorem ipsum
\end{document}
```

Note different space in output:

[image]

In classes like `scrbook` (*book (KOMA-script)* in LyX) this spacing isn't an issue, as the chapter titles are set similar to `\section` in the standard classes.

Answer (score 0):

I think today there is a better solution (I don't know if it was possible back than). Typing in `Document->settings->Local Layout` the following:

```
ModifyStyle Chapter
    KeepEmpty   1
End
```

Prevent LyX from removing empty chapters.